# Handle a 24 hour token from API

Tags: python

I'm working with an API that gives me a 24 hours token. Wath I'm doing is saving this token in a json file and in addition the timestamp when I saving it too.

It can be three possibilities:

- Don't exists the json file. In that case I login and create the json file.
- The file exists but more than 24 hours have passed. In that case I login and create the json file.
- The file exists and less than 24 hours have passed. It's ok, I just select the token from it.

This is my code right now:

```
if not os.path.isfile('temp/24h_session.json'):
    token = self.login()
    data = {'token': token, 'timestamp':dt.timestamp(dt.now())}
    with open("temp/24h_session.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
else:
    with open('temp/24h_session.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if data['timestamp'] <= dt.timestamp(dt.now() - timedelta(hours = 24)):
        token = self.login()
        data = {'token': token, 'timestamp':dt.timestamp(dt.now())}
        with open("temp/24h_session.json", "w") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(data))
    else:
        token = data['token']
```

I'm not happy with it, you think its possible to join the first two possibilities to avoid repeat code? I tried with `try/except` but the result was similar because the problem is when the file exists but the more than 24 hour have passed.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem.  I think your logic is clear here.  If you want to avoid duplication you can write a separate utility function like `generate_new_token()` which would both write it to a file and return the new token:

```py
def generate_new_token(filename):
    token = self.login()
    data = {'token': token, 'timestamp':dt.timestamp(dt.now())}
    with open("filename", "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
    return token

token_filename = 'temp/24h_session.json'

if not os.path.isfile(token_filename):
    token = generate_new_token(token_filename)
else:
    with open(token_filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if data['timestamp'] <= dt.timestamp(dt.now() - timedelta(hours = 24)):
        token = generate_new_token(token_filename)
    else:
        token = data['token']
```